# Using object as key erases type information

Tags: javascript, class, types

In a recent project, I have been using some objects as keys to other objects.  However, after doing so their type information is erased, in that `instanceof` no longer works correctly.

MWE:

```
class Foo {

    toString() {
        return "FOO";
    }

}

var foo = new Foo();
var keyObj = {};
keyObj[foo] = "y";
console.log(foo instanceof Foo);  // true
console.log(Object.keys(keyObj)[0].toString());  // prints "FOO" - this *is* a Foo
console.log(Object.keys(keyObj)[0] instanceof Foo);  // false
```

(evaluated with nodejs)

My questions are:

1. What is causing this behavior?
2. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is causing this behavior?

Property names are strings (or Symbols if you explicitly use a Symbol).

If you try to use a non-string as a property name then it will be implicitly converted to a string.

> How do I fix it?

You can't.

At least not without writing code to explicitly convert the string to an object and then calling that code on the string when you read it.

Comment: That's ... um.  I'll just make a map class to implement the behavior I want.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> What is causing this behavior?

Object keys should be only string or symbol, so when is anything is passed as key that is not of that type, JS tries to convert it to string, so it call's foo.toString() and you get `FOO` as key

> How do I fix it?

Use valid keys in js, you can't use object as keys.